# How to use Table to get average velocities from height and time (Problem 22. Chapter 2 from Book: A Physicist's Guide to Mathematica.)

Tags: table

[image]

[image]

My idea to get the average velocities in question (a) by using Table is that: I will state Height and Time

```
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 0.25}]
{0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1., 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2., 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3., 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4., 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5.}
height = {5.0, 5.75, 6.4, 6.94, 7.38, 7.72, 7.96, 8.1, 8.13, 8.07,7.9, 7.62, 7.25, 6.77, 6.2, 5.52, 4.73, 3.85, 2.86, 1.77, 0.58}
{5., 5.75, 6.4, 6.94, 7.38, 7.72, 7.96, 8.1, 8.13, 8.07, 7.9, 7.62,7.25, 6.77, 6.2, 5.52, 4.73, 3.85, 2.86, 1.77, 0.58}
```

then I will use equation height1 = i2-i1 from height and time = i2-i1 from time and get velocity1 = height1/time1
For ex: v1= (5.75-5)-(0.25-0)
But I just do not know how to take an element from Table.
How can I do that? And if I can do that, how can I solve this problem (22a)?
Thank you for your help !!!

Here are the answers the book gives
[image]

Comment: To Take say the third element of a table: table[[3]]

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to take the element in series, like: Table[(i [[final]])-(i [[initial]]),{i,5,0.58}]. Can I get {0,75,0.65,0.54,...}?

Comment: Say element 3 to 5:   table[[3;;5]]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: By definition, the average velocity is equal to the TotalDistance/TotalTime. That is: `Vaverage=(5-0.58)/5`. Done. In general, this site is not to fulfill school hometasks instead of pupil.

Comment: Hi Sean, it’s time to have some fun with your teacher.  Compute both the distance-averaged speed `Integrate[v[t] {x,0,distance}]/distance`  and the time-averaged speed `Integrate[v[t],{t,0,time}]/time` using the interpolation method below. And then tell the teacher that not enough information was provided to compute the average velocity because velocity is a vector.  So, you assumed that the horizontal component velocity was twice the speed of light.  And, if you are feeling saucy, tell the teacher to be more careful in the future.

Comment: Also, tell the teacher that you were not given the precision of the instruments that measured height and time, so you cannot give a proper answer for average speed because every measurement has instrument errors.  You should also ask the teacher to add uncertainty to any reported result such as this one.

Comment: Also, ask the teacher what shape the rock was.  If it was tumbling, some parts of the rock has a different velocity than others.

Comment: Also, ask the teacher to specify that it was the same rock at each measurement.  You never know unless you ask.

Comment: Finally, ask the teacher why they thought it was necessary to state that the air resistance was negligible, because that had no bearing on the question as posed.  Your time is valuable and you have no patience for such nonsense.

Comment: Don’t repeat the silly noun-verb error from three comments ago.

Comment: I am really sorry If you all feel annoyed because I have asked several "silly" questions recently. My teacher asked me to read and try to understand as much as possible the book A Physicist's Guide to Mathematica. I tried to find the answers to some of my problems online, but I can't find them anywhere so this platform is the only way I can find out the answers to my questions, even though I know that this site is not the site to fulfill homework. You guys were so kind to answer all my questions. I really appreciate that.

Comment: This is one of the problems in that book, and above are all the information the problem gives so I think I can not ask the teacher for more information. Here is the answer for the problem (a), {3., 2.6, 2.16, 1.76, 1.36, 0.96, 0.56, 0.12, -0.24, -0.68, -1.12,
-1.48, -1.92, -2.28, -2.72, -3.16, -3.52, -3.96, -4.36, -4.76}. I don't know how to get this answer using Table, that's why I'm asking. 
To be more specific, this problem number 22 is used to revise Chapter 2 in the book. 
I don't know why but I feel like I'm making you guys feel mad. I am really sorry for that

Comment: @Sean Don't worry--it's not annoying at all.  As a professor, I'm happy when students answer a question and subsequently write something snarky that goes beyond the "work they needed to do" and are thinking as well as "doing".  Your teacher will definitely remember you, and that is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing that. Have a nice day ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica has more advanced methods of data analysis. Put together the two list and transpose them to a list of pairs

```
  tb =  {time, height}\[Transpose]
```

No construct an order 2 interpolation by splines,  with continuous velocity but discountinuous acceleration that exhibits errors in the accuracy of the tables

```
  hight[t_] = Interpolation[tb,  InterpolationOrder -> 2]

  Plot[Evaluate[({#, D[#, t], D[#, t, t]} &)[height[t]]], 
        {t, 0, 5}, 
         PlotLabels -> {"height", "velocity", "accelaration"}]
```

[image: free vertical fall]

Answer (score 3):

Two more methods to get the right values from someone who wouldn't use `Table` to do this task:

```
Rest[Interpolation[Transpose@{time, height},
     InterpolationOrder -> 1]'["ValuesOnGrid"]] == 
 Differences[height]/Differences[time]
(*  True  *)
```

The second method with `Differences[]` is worth knowing, imo.

*Hint for `Table[]`:*
`Table[myTab[[i+1]] - myTab[[i]], {i, Length[myTab] - 1}]` computes `Differences[myTab]` for a list `myTab`.

Comment: Thank you a million. Thanks to your answer, I found out the way to answer this question. Luv <3

Comment: @Sean You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the brilliant comments and answers, I came up with this.

Here is a first way to solve the problem using `Differences`.

```
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 0.25}]
(*{0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1., 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2., 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.,3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4., 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5.}*)

height = {5.0, 5.75, 6.4, 6.94, 7.38, 7.72, 7.96, 8.1, 8.13, 8.07, 7.9, 7.62, 7.25, 6.77, 6.2, 5.52, 4.73, 3.85, 2.86, 1.77, 0.58};

dentatime = Differences[time]
(*{0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25}*)

dentaheight = Differences[height]
(*{0.75, 0.65, 0.54, 0.44, 0.34, 0.24, 0.14, 0.03, -0.06, -0.17, -0.28,-0.37, -0.48, -0.57, -0.68, -0.79, -0.88, -0.99, -1.09, -1.19}*)

velocity = dentaheight/dentatime
(*{3., 2.6, 2.16, 1.76, 1.36, 0.96, 0.56, 0.12, -0.24, -0.68, -1.12,-1.48, -1.92, -2.28, -2.72, -3.16, -3.52, -3.96, -4.36, -4.76}*)

avgvelocity = Table[velocity, 1]
(*{{3., 2.6, 2.16, 1.76, 1.36, 0.96, 0.56, 0.12, -0.24, -0.68, -1.12, -1.48, -1.92, -2.28, -2.72, -3.16, -3.52, -3.96, -4.36, -4.76}}*)
```

---

I still want to use `Table` but it seems a bit silly.

Here is a second way using Table[].

```
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 5, 0.25}];
height = {5.0, 5.75, 6.4, 6.94, 7.38, 7.72, 7.96, 8.1, 8.13, 8.07, 7.9, 7.62, 7.25, 6.77, 6.2, 5.52, 4.73, 3.85, 2.86, 1.77, 0.58};

Table[(height[[i + 1]] - height[[i]])/(time[[i + 1]] - time[[i]]),
  {i, Length[time] - 1}]
(*{3., 2.6, 2.16, 1.76, 1.36, 0.96, 0.56, 0.12, -0.24, -0.68,-1.12, -1.48, -1.92, -2.28, -2.72, -3.16, -3.52, -3.96, -4.36, -4.76}*)
```

Yup, never feel better ^V^